# rdf: How to create fqns Enumerated value for a resource

Tags: xml, rdf, jena, enumeration

I am using Apache Jena to create rdf-xml format. How can I create fully qualified name space `enumerated value` outputted on the xml etc: http://longurl#CarType.van OR http://longurl#CarType.hatchback. My approach will create a resource with shorten ID which is not desired etc(#CarType.van) because I have set the output to RDF/XML-ABBREV. I still need to set the output to RDF/XML-ABBREV although.

So, normally it is resolved to the relatively to the base uri like the following but it has a relative id:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0">
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
        xmlns:ns="http://longurl#">
      <ns:IamACAR rdf:ID="abcdedfg">
        <ns:attributetype rdf:resource="#CarType.van"/>
      </ns:IamACAR>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

How to get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
        xmlns:ns="http://longurl#">
      <ns:IamACAR rdf:ID="abcdedfg">
        <ns:attributetype rdf:resource="http://longurl#CarType.van"/>
      </ns:IamACAR>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: The RDF encoded is the same - it does not matter. Theer are some controls for output:  see the documentation: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html#advanced-rdfxml-output

Comment: That's not legal XML.  What is that semicolon doing after `<?xml version="1.0">;`?  And the extra double quotation mark after `longurl#""`?